# What does "Meiner schon" mean?

Tags: translation

In the dialog of a Tatort episode, one of the detectives says to a subject "Hübscher Wagen.", to which he replies

> Meiner schon. Ich kann ihn auch fahren.

I don't understand anything about this reply. Of course, I understand the literal meaning of the words ("Mine already. I can also drive it."), but it does not make any sense, so I figure there must be a better interpretation.

In case it matters, in this scene, the subject was driving along the street (in a nice-looking red Porsche) when the detectives block his way with their car. The dialogue described above ensues.

Comment: "Meiner schon" --> "Mine actually is" (as opposed to yours/that other one). "Ich kann ihn auch fahren" --> "and I know how to drive it too" (as opposed to the driver of that other car).

Comment: Please provide a link to the minute of that dialog.

Comment: @userunknown: it starts at around 00:25:40 of http://www.ardmediathek.de/tv/Tatort/Wendehammer/Das-Erste/Video?bcastId=602916&documentId=48425120 , but the link will probably not work after 2018.01.14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't seen that episode, but it's apparently a snarky response one could come up with reacting to a possibly unintentional road block done with a presumably *lesser* car.

> "Meiner schon."

translates within context - and including connotation - to "Well, *my* car indeed is beautiful - as opposed to yours".

> "Ich kann ihn auch fahren."

is probably a side swipe towards the driver of the blocking car, suggesting that the subject is capable of handling the car, as opposed to the addressee.

All of this makes sense if the subject is annoyed by the block, is quite arrogant in the perception of his car, and convinced that the road block is due to a rather unintentional mistake of the other driver.

PS: The fragmentary dialog leaves out a good deal, so the context was quite important, yes.